# Remove duplicates in List<Map<String, Object>> using Streams in java

Tags: java, collections, java-8, stream

`List<Map<String, Object>> apptlist = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sb.toString());`

Here I got a list. In that list duplicate maps are showing. I need to remove those duplicates using Java 8 Stream. Can anybody help me?

I tried Stream this

```
Set<Map<String, Object>> set = new HashSet<>();
apptlist.stream().map(s -> s.toLowerCase()).filter(s -> !set.contains(s)).forEach(set::add);
```

and this

```
apptlist.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but I didn't get any results. Still, I am getting duplicates.

Comment: Do the values of the map implement `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: No sir. Values Implemented in `equals`.

Comment: duplicate in what sense? Are some maps entirely equal? i.e. they are the same size and contain the exact same key-value-pairs?

Comment: Btw: whenever I see `Map<String, Object>`, that seems suspiciously like some business-object. Which would be best placed inside its own class.

Comment: “Still, I am getting duplicates” You are not. This code doesn’t even pass the compiler.

Comment: yes, @Holger. Still, I am getting duplicates.

Comment: How can you invoke `toLowerCase()` on a `Map`? Besides that, a `Set` doesn’t contain duplicates *by definition*. That’s why the `.filter(s -> !set.contains(s))` is pointless; the `add` method won’t add duplicates anyway. Except when you have a different idea of “duplicate” than Java. But in that case, the `contains` check still is pointless, as it uses the same definition of “duplicate” as `Set.add`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the stream API, creating a `Set` will elimnate duplicates:

```
Set<Map<String, Object>> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

Provided that, equals map has the same keys, and the values associated to that keys in the Maps implements `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are equal when their length equals and for every key map1[key].equals(map2[key])

`String` has a proper equals method in java but `Object` does not.
Default `equals` implementation for Object compares the address of the object, not its fields values.

We can see your code works properly when using values with proper `equals` method such as `Integer`

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map1.put("a", 1);
    map1.put("b", 2);

    map2.put("a", 1);
    map2.put("b", 2);

    List<Map<String, Integer>> mapList = Arrays.asList(map1, map2);

    System.out.println(mapList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

```
[{a=1, b=2}]
```